# How to create custom valid Url Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, frontend

I am trying to create a regex for first time for the URL having following conditions:

1. Starts with or without the www
2. Do not starts with http:// or https://
3. Allowed special characters are: hyphen (-) and dot (.)
4. Ends with a TLD like: .com, .io, .co.in, etc.

Some of the examples for reference:

**Valid:**

```
xyz.com
xyz-px.com
www.xyz.com
abc.xyz.px.io
www.abc.xyz.px.io
```

**Invalid:**

```
xyz-.com
xy_pm.com
http://xyz.io
https://xyz.io
http://www.pm.xyz
xy@pzzzz.com
xyz.io$#
www.xy
xyz.io-
```

I have created a regex

`/(^(?!https|http)?:\/\/(www\.?)[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})/gi`

But it is not working as desired.

Comment: Maybe like `^[^\W_]+(?:[-.][^\W_]+)*(?:\.[a-z]{2,})+$` https://regex101.com/r/E08Ce3/1

Comment: It won't work for the fouth condition ending with Top Level Domain

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: www.xy it becomes valid url but it is not

Comment: You could list all the valid ones `^[^\W_]+(?:[-.][^\W_]+)*\.(?:io|com)$`

Comment: Great! This will work in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use

```
^[^\W_]+(?:[-.][^\W_]+)*\.(?:io|com)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\W_]+` Match 1+ word chars without an `_`
- `(?:[-.][^\W_]+)*` Optionally repeat matching `.` or `-` and 1+ word chars without `_`
- `\.` Match a literal dot
- `(?:io|com)` Match any of the alternatives
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/971sEl/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?!(http|https):\/\/)(?:www\.)?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9])(?:[-\.][a-zA-Z0-9])?)+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

[DEMO - REGEXR](https://regexr.com/5v0do)

And the flowchart is:
[image]

Comment: How to make sure that the string ends with a tld because now it can validate www.xy which is not a valid URL

Comment: That's very hard to do this because there could be more than [1000 top level domain](https://www.theregister.com/2015/07/10/there_are_now_1000_internet_extensions/)

Comment: Yess but at the end there must be any top level domain not necessarily .com,.in it can have .xyz or anything ,ie. www.xy.xy is allowed but not www.xy

Answer (score -1):

The modified regex is

```
/^(?!(https|http):\/\/)(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:.[^\s\W]{2,})+$/gi
```

https://regex101.com/r/aNy8St/1

Comment: Explain your modifications please.

Comment: It won't work in case we want the urls to end with a TLD like: .com, .io, .co.in, etc.

Comment: There's no need to bother with the 'www' part - it's just a subdomain, which is handled already by the next capture group.